# rqt_graph GUI not working

Tags: ros, rqt-graph, rqt

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am following the steps described in "Understanding ROS Topics" tutorial.

When I try to launch rqt_graph in the console I get this output:

```
    user@user:~$ rosrun rqt_graph rqt_graph 
Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored
```

Which I believe is a normal output.

The rqt graph window opens but nothing is shown in it.

I don't know what could be wrong.

Thank you,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/62204/rqt_graph-gui-not-working/) by [Pino](https://answers.ros.org/users/4831/pino/) on ROS Answers with karma: 88 on 2013-05-06

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Pino](https://answers.ros.org/users/4831/pino/) on 2013-05-06**:
Here is a screenshot of what I'm seeing: http://screencloud.net/v/qpXV

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2013-05-06**:
This screenshot helps more to understand what's happening, and that looks odd. What happens when you run `$ rqt` from command line and open "Plugins" --> "Graph" on it?

**Comment by [Pino](https://answers.ros.org/users/4831/pino/) on 2013-05-06**:
This works, now I can see the graph as shown here: http://screencloud.net/v/2bR7
But trying to run it directly using
$ rosrun rqt_graph rqt_graph
still doesn't work

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2013-05-06**:
@Pino so if you open `rqt_graph` via `rqt`, not directly, do you see nodes & topics or whatever you wanted to see?

**Comment by [Pino](https://answers.ros.org/users/4831/pino/) on 2013-06-10**:
Yes, opening via rqt solves the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`AttributeError` seems to be [python's bug](http://answers.ros.org/question/34304/exception-attributeerror-when-starting-roscore/), not ROS, as you might already be aware of.

I just ran that tutorial and have no problem with it. Make sure your terminal you use points to `ros master` where your nodes running with. It can be verified by commands like:

```
$ echo $ROS_MASTER_URI 
http://localhost:11311  (you should see this if you're running master on local machine and made no change to port number)
```

---

Update 5/8/13, copying from my comment section) Work around might be to open `rqt_graph` from `rqt`'s integrated GUI by:

```
$ rqt
```

and open "Plugins" --> "Graph".

In the 2nd snapshot you shared, graph is not yet shown. Do you just forget to take snapshot where graph is shown? Or does the graph not appear yet even though everything else is working correctly (if so that's still a problem. Might be worth opening a ticket on github)?

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2013-05-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Pino](https://answers.ros.org/users/4831/pino/) on 2013-05-06**:
Yes, I first believed this was the source of the problem but checked and it's a common error.
I did what you suggested and got your same response:
$ echo $ROS_MASTER_URI
http://localhost:11311